# IntelliJ shows subpackages separately in project view

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to see subpackage in a tree view, not separately subpackages like this: 
[image]

Where do i have to set that option in intelliJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the gear icon at the top-right of the view, and uncheck "Flatten packages"